# XE_FILE_TARGET_TVF WaitType in Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database

Recently I started exploring Azure Sql and came across waittype XE_FILE_TARGET_TVF. I tried searching online to get more info but didn't get enough information.

I am just curious to know:

- What does this waittype mean ?
- Is it only specific to Azure SQL ?
- How does it affect sql query performance ?

Comment: Check out this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/a/36202343/2975396

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here: https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/xe_file_target_tvf/

> This wait type is when a thread is waiting for data to be returned when using the sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file table-value function to read event data from a file target.

this has no affect on SQL server performance and also applied to SQL on premise and Azure SQL.